# How to make a request HTTP in Android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I want to make a request whith method `POST` or `GET`.

I just try with method `POST` but I don't have success.

Here is my URL: http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php

These are my values:

```
UID=login

correo=test@gmail.com

password=123456

idDevice=PRUEBA01

arg1=Droid

arg2=JellyBean

arg3=IMEI
```

If you copy/paste in the browser:

```
http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php?UID=login&correo=test@gmail.com&password=123456&idDevice=PRUEBA01&arg1=Droid&arg2=JellyBean&arg3=IMEI
```

The answer will be:

```
[{"idUsuario":129,"nombreCompleto":"test1 test ","correo":"test@gmail.com","idcentroDefault":1}]
```

And, I want to show this in a `TextView`

My Code:

```
public void enviar(View vista) throws IOException {

   String txt = executeHttpPost();

    displayMessange(txt);

   /* String query =  executeHttpPost("http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php");
    displayMessange(query);*/

}

public void displayMessange(String message) {
    TextView query = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.query);
    query.setText(message);
}


public String executeHttpPost() throws IOException {


    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        String contraseña = password.getText().toString();
        String usuario = user.getText().toString();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php");



        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UID", usuario));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correo","test@gmail.com"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", contraseña));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idDevice", "PRUEBA01"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg1", "Droid"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg2", "JellyBean"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg3", "IMEI"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,"UTF-8"));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String datos = convertStreamToString(is);
        return datos;





    }
    catch(Exception e) { return "error";}


}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

My aplication have the User and Password from two `EditText`s.

`android:id="@+id/password` where I write login
`android:id="@+id/user` where I write `123456`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/wallhaven">

<TextView
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:backgroundTintMode="add"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<EditText

    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="User"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

<EditText
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="password"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Query"
    android:id="@+id/query"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enviar"
    android:onClick="enviar"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/send" />
```

But I just receive a request with the message **error**.

Comment: Can you put up your php code also?

Comment: A can't I don't have access :(

Comment: Oh....your android code looked good, so I thought it might be a problem with the php. I would recommend doing all the http requests in an Async Task though.

Comment: In the browser you execute a GET request. So your android code is wrong. Do not use HttpPost as a POST request will be executed. That will not work if the server expects a GET only. Please show your php script.

Comment: Thank I will continue find whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

use this code for get the result after a request of url

```
URL link = new URL("http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

String body = "UID=login&correo=test@gmail.com&password=123456&idDevice=PRUEBA01&arg1=Droid&arg2=JellyBean&arg3=IMEI";

int ch;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

conn.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("UTF8"));
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
    sb.append((char) ch);
    }

is.close();
conn.disconnect();
String result = sb.toString();
```

Of course, this is for your case, you can create a class and pass url and body, make sure handle IOException in your class.

The result is the json, of course, if your url works fine.

If you pass body to the class, use URL Encoder to UTF-8, for avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test based on your code :

```
{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://test.anakel.mx/utils/webservice.php");

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UID", "login"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correo","test@gmail.com"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idDevice", "PRUEBA01"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg1", "Droid"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg2", "JellyBean"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arg3", "IMEI"));

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String datos = convertStreamToString(is);

            System.out.println("========  " + datos + "  ========");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the result getting from response : 
[image]

It looks worked perfectly.

Plz check your permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, it should have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in there.

And one more thing I also have noticed that in your code, it seems have some special characters like this :

```
String contraseña = password.getText().toString();
```

try to avoid it, just change it to regular English characters instead.

Have a good luck!